# Concurrent collection

Tags: multithreading, grails, concurrency, groovy, java.util.concurrent

I have a bunch of threads, each which create a lot of objects.  As each object is created I need to check a collection of existing objects to make sure make sure an equal object hasn't already been created by another thread.  If an equal object hasn't already been created then I need to  add the object that was just created to the list of existing objects.  So basically I need a mutex on a list.

I was thinking of doing something like this, but I don't know if there is a better way to do it in Groovy:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock

class FooService {

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock()
    private def existingObjectList = []

    def longRunningProcess(params) {
        // create a bunch of threads that will all use someMethod
    }

    private def someMethod(def propertiesMap) {
        def obj = new Foo(propertiesMap) // create an object

        lock.lock() // lock the existing object list
        try {
            if(!existingObjectList.contains(obj)) {
                existingObjectList.add(obj)
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock() // unlock the existing object list
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.**  I don't think it will matter but this code is in a Grails service and I'm using the [Grails Executor plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/executor) to create the threads.

Comment: Have you looked at [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)?

Comment: @tim_yates I did look at them, but reading through their descriptions it didn't look like a thread would have exclusive access for a read operation immediately followed by a write operation. I cannot have thread `A` read from the collection and have thread `B` read from the collection before thread `A` has a chance to write to the collection.

Comment: There's [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29)

Comment: @tim_yates that looks promising! I'll give it a try before I go the full blown mutex route.  Since I only need a list and not a map I guess I'll just use my objects as the key, and use an empty string for the value (since `null` isn't allowed)?

Comment: Apache seems to use `ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Boolean>` for [it's implementation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/mina/branches/mina-2-cleanup/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mina/util/ConcurrentHashSet.java) of `ConcurrentHashSet`